# Is it possible to add a flag to a specific role user without using VIEW module?

Tags: views, users, flags

I have downloaded **[profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)** module and I have created a specific role called  **artist**. I also added some fields so to be shown only for the artist role users' on the registration form.
Then I added a flag and selected flag type as **profile2**.
Now I selected **Artist** profile bundle.
Now the problem is that the flag which I just created is being displayed on Artist user's profile view only after we add a value to one of the form fields for that particular Artist user. Is there a way to resolve this without the use of **Views**?